# How to show long strings in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I have a text file containing long and short strings and I can open it in Eclipse. But the weird thing is that I am not able to see the long strings explicitly; they are shown as blank. Only short strings are shown. If I place cursor at one of the long strings, then press "End" to go to the end of that line, it goes to a very far column; in comparison, if I do the same for the short strings or truly empty strings, it stops at the correct places. So in this sense, Eclipse IDE does tell me that the line which is shown as blank does contain a lot stuff. But why it is not showing it?

Has anybody experienced this issue too?

Comment: Sounds like a platform specific problem.  I have never seen this on Windows.

Comment: Try unzipping Eclipse again, start with a new workspace, create a new empty Java project, and copy the problematic file with Ctrl-C Ctrl-V into the new empty Java project.  If you see it correctly now, some setting was messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program in a command prompt using the complied JAR file. If it works in the command prompt (or terminal), ignore the error, since it is simply an error with the way Eclipse displays strings. If it persists in whichever prompt, then you know it's an error with the way you're handling the string.

Comment: it is not a java program issue per se. It is a display text file issue with Eclipse. I can use other text editors to see the content of the file.

Comment: Oh, sorry. In that case, I would just ignore it, and edit the text file in a separate editor. I know it sounds silly, but IDEs aren't always perfect, so the user sometimes needs to accommodate for things that don't work, but should.